# Curl command error: returns something looking like javascript

Tags: curl

Now,I am trying to use curl command and check if my code works fine.
And I think the last I tried but this time somehow it doesn't work and the result returned looks like raw html and Javascript.

I am guessing the curl command is wrong or there may be something.

Please give me any advices.

This is what I tried.

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/internal/items/209?api_token=uabsubsfasjbbaljbd" -X DELETE
```

or

```
curl -X delete "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/internal/items/209?api_token=uabsubsfasjbbaljbd"
```

the error looks like this

```
    case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40: // disable using arrow keys on completing
      return true;
  }

  return false;
};

Autocomplete.prototype.trim = function(from, needToTrim) {
  var self = this;
  var num = 5;

  if (this.elements.length > num) {
    (0 < from ? removeClass : addClass)(this.prefix, 'trimmed');
    (from + num < this.elements.length ? removeClass : addClass)(this.suffix, 'trimmed');
  } else {
    addClass(this.prefix, 'trimmed');
    addClass(this.suffix, 'trimmed');
  }

  function iterate(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i, ++x) if (0 <= x && x < self.elements.length) {
      toggleClass(self.elements[x], 'trimmed');
    }
  }


  }

  resizerElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    function recordConsoleElementHeight(event) {
      resizerElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', recordConsoleElementHeight);

      var currentConsoleElementHeight = consoleElement.offsetHeight;
      setContainerElementBottomMargin(currentConsoleElementHeight);
    }

    resizerElement.addEventListener('mouseup', recordConsoleElementHeight);
  });
});

}).call(this);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

thank you.

Comment: The remote server sent you that javascript. It's not an error on your side -- curl is behaving perfectly in printing out what the server sends it -- it's the server doing something you didn't expect.

Comment: I'd suggest telling curl to log your headers so you can see if this javascript is part of something like a 404 or 500 error page. You might need to add some headers (like maybe a `Content-Type` header) to get a response in a format you expect instead of HTML, but that's something that the server's API reference is the best source for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.
I just added the header with this `-H 'Content-Type:application/json'` but nothing has changed. I am still looking for other solutions.

Comment: Again, we can't offer _any_ solution here because we don't have the source code for your server. Stack Overflow is not a place for guesses and speculative answers, or questions that don't provide enough information to permit a conclusive answer (making guesses and speculative answers the only possibility) -- we want questions that have enough details that they can be given provably-correct answers. (That's why we ask for a [mre] -- so people can reproduce the problem themselves and test their answers, as well as those given by others).

Comment: In terms of how to _collect_ more details, I would suggest you inspect the response headers the server is sending you. If the page with the javascript is a 404 page, for example, that tells you a lot -- same if it's a 403 (in which case you know your API token isn't being accepted). But really, once again, you need to look at the server side, not at the `curl` call you're invoking it with.

Comment: Really, since the same command _did_ work in the past and doesn't work now, that implies that it's a 403 page because your API token timed out. But that's still guesswork, not a provably-correct answer, because _only someone who can inspect your server and knows how its API tokens work_ can give a provably-correct answer, and you haven't told us anything at all about what that server is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It helped a lot! Now it works!